# Magento observer not trigger after running product import profile

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.7

I have create a new custom events with name "catalog_product_import_profile_after". this event call after product import run profile completed process. if I run profile for 2 products then it is working fine and custom event is triggered but when I run same profile for thousands of products, it's working and custom event is not triggered.

Here is the code for observer.php file --

```
<?php
class GWB_ClearOrphan_Model_Observer
{

            public function disableProducts(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

                try{    
                    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id',9)
                            ->load();
                }
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    //Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'collection.log');
                }

                try{
                    $resource = Mage::getModel('core/resource');
                    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
                    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                }
                catch(Exception $e) {
                    //Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'developer.log');
                }

                foreach($collection as $val) {
                    $sku = $val->getSku();

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM feed_products WHERE feed_sku='".$sku."'";
                    $results = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $feed_sku = $results[0]['feed_sku'];

                    if($feed_sku != ''){
                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
                        $product->setStatus(2);
                        try {
                            $product->save();
                            //$product->delete();
                        }
                        catch (Exception $e) {
                            Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, 'product_disable.log');
                        }   
                    }               
                }

                try{
                    $writeConnection->query("TRUNCATE TABLE feed_products");
                } 
                catch(Exception $e){
                    echo $e;
                }
            }

}

?>
```

I have registered this event under "ProfileController.php" file, here is the code for this function ---

```
<?php

    public function batchFinishAction()
        {   
            $batchId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($batchId) {
                $batchModel = Mage::getModel('dataflow/batch')->load($batchId);
                /* @var $batchModel Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch */

                if ($batchModel->getId()) {
                    $result = array();
                    try {
                        $batchModel->beforeFinish();
                    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                        $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        $result['error'] = Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('An error occurred while finishing process. Please refresh the cache');
                    }

            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_import_profile_after', array('adapter'=>$this));

                    $batchModel->delete();
                    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
                }
            }
        }

?>
```

Comment: can you post the code where you are triggering your event?

Comment: @Andrew I have update the code of function where i registered events. please chech updated code.

Comment: I didn't see any bugs on your code. I hope, errors will be in batch process running. could you please check it that too..

Answer (score 0):

It depends in which note of confir you fire your event.
This could be if you run your batch process from backend or cli and fired your event in "frontend" node. Here it's better to describe configuration for this event in global node.